# Find algorithm : Reconstruct a sequence with the minimum length combination of disjointed subsequences chosen from a list of subsequences

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I do not know if it’s appropriate to ask this question here so sorry if it is not.

**I got a sequence ALPHA, for example :**

```
A B D Z A B X
```

**I got a list of subsequences of ALPHA, for example :**

```
A B D
B D
A B
D Z
A
B
D
Z
X
```

I search an algorithm that **find the minimum length of disjointed subsequences** that reconstruct ALPHA, for example in our case :

```
{A B D} {Z} {A B} {X}
```

Any ideas? My guess is something already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform this problem into finding a minimum path in a graph.

The nodes will correspond to prefixes of the string, including one for the empty string. There will be an edge from a node A to a node B if there is an allowed sub-sequence that, when appended to the string prefix A, the result is the string prefix B.

The question is now transformed into finding the minimum path in the graph starting from the node corresponding to the empty string, and ending in the node corresponding to the entire input string.

You can now apply *e.g.* BFS (since the edges have uniform costs), or Dijkstra's algorithm to find this path.

---

The following python code is an implementation based on the principles above:

```py
def reconstruct(seq, subseqs):
    n = len(seq)

    d = dict()
    for subseq in subseqs:
        d[subseq] = True

    # in this solution, the node with value v will correspond
    # to the substring seq[0: v]. Thus node 0 corresponds to the empty string
    # and node n corresponds to the entire string

    # this will keep track of the predecessor for each node
    predecessors = [-1] * (n + 1)
    reached = [False] * (n + 1)
    reached[0] = True

    # initialize the queue and add the first node
    # (the node corresponding to the empty string)
    q = []
    qstart = 0
    q.append(0)

    while True:
        # test if we already found a solution
        if reached[n]:
            break

        # test if the queue is empty
        if qstart > len(q):
            break

        # poll the first value from the queue
        v = q[qstart]
        qstart += 1

        # try appending a subsequence to the current node
        for n2 in range (1, n - v + 1):
            # the destination node was already added into the queue
            if reached[v + n2]:
                continue

            if seq[v: (v + n2)] in d:
                q.append(v + n2)
                predecessors[v + n2] = v
                reached[v + n2] = True

    if not reached[n]:
        return []

    # reconstruct the path, starting from the last node
    pos = n
    solution = []
    while pos > 0:
        solution.append(seq[predecessors[pos]: pos])
        pos = predecessors[pos]
    solution.reverse()

    return solution


print reconstruct("ABDZABX", ["ABD", "BD", "AB", "DZ", "A", "B", "D", "Z", "X"])
```

I don't have much experience with python, that's the main reason why I preferred to stick to the basics (*e.g.* implementing a queue with a list + an index to the start).

Comment: Wow, complexity looks huge! Actually I got 10,000 sequences of length 70. I can work on Python or R, do you think it's possible to do it in less than 8 hours on a 8 Go RAM pc?

Comment: i'll think of some optimizations - what is the length of the string to be reconstructed?

Comment: Around 70 like I said. But the number of available subsequences to reconstruct each of 10,000 sequences is around one thousand. But subsequences are stored as blocks of nested subsequences. Maybe it can help.

Comment: ah, i understand - i think it would fit in 8 hours, i'll try coming up with some python code a little bit later.

Comment: I added the code, i expect it would run in about an hour for the 10,000 sequences. If you intend to use it, please let me know how it goes!

Comment: Can you give me your email, I would like to know your advice about a specific problem? Thanks, awesome work! Btw is that BFS or dijkstra algorithm?

Comment: the code is based on BFS. i'll write in a separate message the information about my e-mail address, and then i'll remove it from here once you confirm noting it :)